# Why splash activity crashed?

Tags: android, splash-screen

I try implement splash in my app. Splash activity run but after execute ondestroy method crashed app.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
           getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
           TimerTask splash = new TimerTask(){
                public void run() {
                    onDestroy();
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Collection_List_Activity.class));
                }
            };

            Timer splashScreenTimer = new Timer();
            // Timer set to 4.5 seconds
            splashScreenTimer.schedule(splash, 1000);

    }
```

Comment: android calls `onDestroy();`. Get rid of the call.

Comment: Ok. I want after start new activity To be closed splash activity

Comment: You should not have a separate Activity for a splash screen, the correct Android way is to use the Theme to show custom content before the first Activity loads, see here: https://plus.google.com/+IanLake/posts/SW7F2CJvAmU

Comment: you can finish your activity in onPause() method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not be calling `onDestroy` manually. It's an activity lifecycle method and lifecycle method are not meant to be called manually. You should be using `finish()` instead.